# Doxygen Linux "make install" error

Tags: linux, installation, doxygen, doxywizard

I try to install doxygen on my linux 2.3.32. `./configure` runs fine. But `make install` throws a error

```
/usr/bin/install: call stat for "bin/doxywizard" not possible: file or directory not found
```

In fact, there is no such a file. But how can I solve that?

edit:

Output

```
-003:~/Downloads/doxygen-1.2.11$ ./configure && sudo make && make install
  Checking for GNU install tool... using /usr/bin/install
  Created Makefile from Makefile.in...
/usr/bin/install -d /usr/local/bin
/usr/bin/install -d /usr/local/doc/doxygen
/usr/bin/install -m 755 bin/doxygen    /usr/local/bin
/usr/bin/install -m 755 bin/doxytag    /usr/local/bin
/usr/bin/install -m 755 bin/doxysearch /usr/local/bin
/usr/bin/install -m 755 bin/doxywizard /usr/local/bin
/usr/bin/install: Aufruf von stat für „bin/doxywizard“ nicht möglich: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
make: *** [install] Fehler 1
```

Comment: Well, did the previous output from make say anything about building doxywizard?

Comment: @Useless I posted it as well ( edited)

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not using the compiled binaries?

Comment: @Chris, the pre-compiled binaries package does not include the Doxywizard GUI.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15020691/installation-of-doxygen-and-error-in-make-command

Answer (score 1):

You do the

```
$> make install
```

directly after configuring. The install target is usually only meant to copy/link the generated binaries to their destination directories. Beforehand, you need to actually compile them by running

```
$> make
```

Comment: Can you then please post the *full* log of the commands you ran and the output you saw?

Comment: Here you are. The full output

Comment: Can you try a "make clean" and re-run? The log output looks like the configure run does not finish and that "make install" is directly executed before anything is built. This looks weird.