# Installation of doxygen and error in make command

Tags: makefile, installation, centos, doxygen

I am trying to install doxygen in my CentOs 6.3 machine and I am getting this error. Any ideas??

```
[root@dell1 doxygen-1.8.3.1]# make install
/usr/bin/install -d /usr/local/bin
/usr/bin/install -d /usr/local/doc/doxygen
/usr/bin/install -m 755 bin/doxygen    /usr/local/bin
/usr/bin/install -m 755 bin/doxytag    /usr/local/bin
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat `bin/doxytag': No such file or directory
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

Comment: Can you post your top-level `Makefile` on [pasteBin](http://pastebin.com/)?

Comment: It looks like doxygen-1.8.4 binaries lack as well the doxytag, so that the only way is to modify the Makefile.in or Makefile and comment the installation of bin/doxytag. It is actually only one of the tools for doxygen, and not the most important one.

Comment: From the doxygen 1.8.0 release notes: The tool doxytag has been declared obsolete and is removed (it wasn't working properly anyway). Same goes for the installdox script.

Answer (score 19):

Bash isn't wrong in complaining:

```
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat `bin/doxytag': No such file or directory
```

It happens to be that the compiled file *doxytag* was not included in the downloaded tar file. So when you try to *make*, it couldn't find that file. To *make* it successfully, you have two options:

### Compile the doxytag.py file from [here](https://github.com/vlfeat/vlfeat/blob/master/docsrc/doxytag.py) and paste it to doxygen's bin directory

You can compile the python file doxytag.py from the above link using:

```
python -m compileall path_to_the_file/doxytag.py
```

It should generate a python compiled executable with .pyc extension. Now move this file to your doxygen-version folder. For example,

```
mv doxytag.pyc your_path/doxygen-1.8.5/bin/doxytag
```

Or alternatively download the doxytag from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fptad4nzc3n22o0/doxytag)

Now when you try to *make*, it will complete without any errors.

### Comment out the line that requires doxytag file from the Makefile

You may read about the doxytag utility from https://www.star.bnl.gov/public/comp/sofi/doxygen/doxytag_usage.html.

If you do not really require this utility in your documentation, simply skip it by commenting out or deleting the line in the Makefile present in the doxygen-1.8.5(as per your version) directory by:

```
#$(INSTTOOL) -m 755 bin/doxytag    $(INSTALL)/bin
```

And then run the *make* command.

Comment: doxytag is not part anymore of the doxygen distribution (since version 1.8.0), tag handling is integrated in doxygen.

Answer (score 4):

The doxygen make is strange: "make install" will not invoke "make", so you need to do a

```
make
make install
```

to first generate the binaries and then install them.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers, the problem was that i should have changed the folder that the make file looks for the doxytag. or to copy doxytag in the last folder.

Answer (score 3):

[A cannot stat error literally means the file(s) or directory does not exist - or you do not have the correct permissions.  If you know where the directory is located - start looking there for permissions and file existence.](http://www.unix.com/unix-advanced-expert-users/27643-cannot-stat-error.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try as a superuser.

```
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll need to install some dependencies.

```bash
sudo apt install cmake
sudo apt install flex
sudo apt install bison
```

After that, execute the commands below; it'll probably work fine.

```bash
git clone https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen.git
cd doxygen
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ..
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: For the current version this is OK but the question was in 2013 and here the procedure didn't use cmake and git at all. Furthermore problem was on the, obsolete, doxytag program