# How to enable markdown support in Doxygen and keep original file extensions?

Tags: markdown, doxygen

I would like to keep the documentation in my code as readable as possible but I also want to automatically generate documentation with Doxygen.

I then want to write the documentation in my code with Markdown syntax but I don't find how to add the Markdown support in Doxygen.

[This page](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/markdown.html) doesn't explain how to add the support and MARKDOWN_SUPPORT = YES in the Doxyfile doesn't have any effect.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and Doxygen 1.7.

EDIT 1 :

- "and keep original file extensions" added to the title
- My problem comes from the extensions I use for my codes. I keep .h and .cpp extensions while .md would be necessary to enable markdown. Is it possible to use markdown and keep the original .h and .cpp extensions?

EDIT 2 :

- Here is an example code (test.h):

  ```
  /**
  * Title test
  * ==========
  * @file test.h
  *
  *   | This  | is     | a     | table |
  *   | :----:| :----: | :----:| :----:|
  *   | x     |   x    |    x  |   x   |
  */
  ```

  The result includes the file in Doxygen because of command @file but the resulting html file display the title and the table as normal text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realized that I was not using Doxygen 1.8.5 as I initially thought but Doxygen 1.7 instead.
Doxygen 1.7 (provided in the Ubuntu repositories) doesn't automatically support Markdown while Doxygen 1.8.5 does.

I then had to install Doxygen 1.8.5 manually (64 bits version [here](http://ftp.stack.nl/pub/users/dimitri/doxygen-1.8.5.linux.bin.tar.gz)) and solved installation problems using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19629765/1474292).

Markdown is now supported natively by Doxygen.