# Doxygen make make install Error : cannot stat ‘examples’: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, debian, installation, doxygen

I am trying to setup doxygen on debian 7. But make and make install throws following errors.

```
# make 
 /usr/bin/install -d /usr/local/bin 
 /usr/bin/install -d /usr/local/doc/doxygen 
 /usr/bin/install -m 755 bin/doxygen    /usr/local/bin 
 /usr/bin/install -m 755 bin/doxytag    /usr/local/bin 
 #/usr/bin/install -m 755 bin/doxywizard /usr/local/bin 
 cp -r html /usr/local/doc/doxygen 
 cp -r examples /usr/local/doc/doxygen 
 cp: cannot stat ‘examples’: No such file or directory 
 Makefile:13: recipe for target 'install' failed 
 make: *** [install] Error 1 

 # make install 
 /usr/bin/install -d /usr/local/bin 
 /usr/bin/install -d /usr/local/doc/doxygen 
 /usr/bin/install -m 755 bin/doxygen    /usr/local/bin 
 /usr/bin/install -m 755 bin/doxytag    /usr/local/bin 
 /usr/bin/install -m 755 bin/doxywizard /usr/local/bin 
 cp -r html /usr/local/doc/doxygen 
 cp -r examples /usr/local/doc/doxygen 
 cp: cannot stat ‘examples’: No such file or directory 
 Makefile:13: recipe for target 'install' failed 
 make: *** [install] Error 1
```

Am I missing something? Anyone experienced similar issues?

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is quite old and the asker has probably found a sol'n or installed another way, but for anyone else finding there way here:

I'm guessing you're installing using the binaries. Have a look in the html folder, and you should see an examples folder in there. I think the changing the `cp -r examples`... line to `cp -r html/examples`... in the makefile should fix things for you. 
I think this is because of the layout of the source files being different from the binaries, and the makefile that comes with the binaries may not have been adjusted to account for that.

Comment: In combination with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15020691/installation-of-doxygen-and-error-in-make-command) and your answer I was finally able to make it run.