# doxygen 1.8.17 clang crashing

Tags: clang, doxygen, ubuntu-18.04

Doxygen is failing with the below output on version 1.8.17 on Ubuntu 18.04.  However, Doxygen 1.8.13 passes with NO issues.

```
Searching for files in directory /home/rgleim/Git/RMS/pb980_dox/BD_GUI_Swarning: source media is not a readable file or directory... skipping.
error: fixed-compilation-database: Error while opening fixed database: No such file or directory
json-compilation-database: Error while opening JSON database: No such file or directory
 using clang compilation database path of: "(null)"
doxygen: /home/dimitri/doxygen/dev/llvm-svn/tools/clang/lib/Sema/SemaExprCXX.cpp:118: clang::ParsedType clang::Sema::getConstructorName(clang::IdentifierInfo&, clang::SourceLocation, clang::Scope*, clang::CXXScopeSpec&, bool): Assertion `InjectedClassName && "couldn't find injected class name"' failed.
libclang: crash detected during parsing: {
  'source_filename' : '(null)'
  'command_line_args' : ['clang', '-I../../../VIKING_COMMON/FileX/groupsrc', '-I../../../VIKING_COMMON/NetX/groupsrc', '-I../../../VIKING_COMMON/NetX-Apps/groupsrc', '-I../../../VIKING_COMMON/NetX-BSD/groupsrc', '-I../../../VIKING_COMMON/USBX/groupsrc', '-I../../../VIKING_COMMON/ThreadX/groupsrc', '-I../../../VIKING_COMMON/Include', '-I../../../BD_GUI_SRC/Alarm-Analysis/groupsrc', '-I../../../BD_GUI_SRC/BD-IO-Devices/groupsrc', '-I../../../BD_GUI_SRC/BdSdAgent/groupsrc', '-I../../../BD_GUI_SRC/Breath-Delivery/groupsrc', '-I../../../BD_GUI_SRC/Build/groupsrc', '-I../../../BD_GUI_SRC/DCI/groupsrc', '-I../../../BD_GUI_SRC/Debug/groupsrc', '-I../../../BD_GUI_SRC/FileSystem/groupsrc', '-I../../../BD_GUI_SRC/Foundation/groupsrc', '-I../../../BD_GUI_SRC/GUI-Applications/groupsrc', '-I../../../BD_GUI_SRC/GUI-Foundations/groupsrc', '-I../../../BD_GUI_SRC/GUI-IO-Devices/groupsrc', '-I../../../BD_GUI_SRC/GUI-Serial-Interface/groupsrc', '-I../../../BD_GUI_SRC/HDMI/groupsrc', '-I../../../BD_GUI_SRC/Kernel/groupsrc', '-I../../../BD_GUI_SRC/Nebulizer/groupsrc', '-I../../../BD_GUI_SRC/NebulizerApp/groupsrc', '-I../../../BD_GUI_SRC/Network-Application/groupsrc', '-I../../../BD_GUI_SRC/NormalModeBkChecks/groupsrc', '-I../../../BD_GUI_SRC/Operating-System/groupsrc', '-I../../../BD_GUI_SRC/OS-Foundation/groupsrc', '-I../../../BD_GUI_SRC/Patient-Data/groupsrc', '-I../../../BD_GUI_SRC/Persistent-Objects/groupsrc', '-I../../../BD_GUI_SRC/POST/groupsrc', '-I../../../BD_GUI_SRC/POST-Library/groupsrc', '-I../../../BD_GUI_SRC/Repository/groupsrc', '-I../../../BD_GUI_SRC/Safety-Net/groupsrc', '-I../../../BD_GUI_SRC/Service-Data/groupsrc', '-I../../../BD_GUI_SRC/Service-Mode/groupsrc', '-I../../../BD_GUI_SRC/Settings-Validation/groupsrc', '-I../../../BD_GUI_SRC/SWAT/groupsrc', '-I../../../BD_GUI_SRC/Sys-Init/groupsrc', '-I../../../BD_GUI_SRC/SysLogs/groupsrc', '-I../../../BD_GUI_SRC/Theta-Bsp/groupsrc', '-I../../../BD_GUI_SRC/TinyXML/groupsrc', '-I../../../BD_GUI_SRC/Trend-Database/groupsrc', '-I../../../BD_GUI_SRC/Update/groupsrc', '-I../../../BD_GUI_SRC/Utilities/groupsrc', '-I../../../BD_GUI_SRC/WebServices/groupsrc', '-ferror-limit=0', '-x', 'c++', '/home/rgleim/Git/RMS/pb980_dox/BD_GUI_SRC/WebServices/groupsrc/ControllersWebPage.cc'],
  'unsaved_files' : [('/home/rgleim/Git/RMS/pb980_dox/BD_GUI_SRC/WebServices/groupsrc/ControllersWebPage.cc', '...', 14046), ('/home/rgleim/Git/RMS/pb980_dox/BD_GUI_SRC/WebServices/groupsrc/ControllersWebPage.hh', '...', 1753), ('/home/rgleim/Git/RMS/pb980_dox/BD_GUI_SRC/WebServices/groupsrc/WebPage.hh', '...', 4861), ('/home/rgleim/Git/RMS/pb980_dox/BD_GUI_SRC/WebServices/groupsrc/WebPageIf.hh', '...', 2306), ('/home/rgleim/Git/RMS/pb980_dox/BD_GUI_SRC/WebServices/groupsrc/HtmlConst.hh', '...', 2518), ('/home/rgleim/Git/RMS/pb980_dox/BD_GUI_SRC/WebServices/groupsrc/Operators_ext.hh', '...', 12710), ('/home/rgleim/Git/RMS/pb980_dox/BD_GUI_SRC/WebServices/groupsrc/ControllersDataXML.hh', '...', 2401)],
  'options' : 1,
}
doxygen: /home/dimitri/doxygen/dev/llvm-svn/tools/clang/lib/Parse/Parser.cpp:433: virtual clang::Parser::~Parser(): Assertion `TemplateIds.empty() && "Still alive TemplateIdAnnotations around?"' failed.
```

1. Installed doxygen 1.8.13 using `sudo apt-get install doxygen`
2. Ran doxygen on my code and config. Doxygen completes successfully as expected.
3. Downloaded binaries for doxygen 1.8.17 using the precompiled binaries from http://www.doxygen.nl/download.html.
4. `make install`didn't work until I commented out `#$(INSTTOOL) -m 755 bin/doxytag    $(INSTALL)/bin` and `#cp -r examples $(INSTALL)/doc/doxygen` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15020691/installation-of-doxygen-and-error-in-make-command).
5. Ran doxygen and the output above was observed.
6. Uninstalled doxygen
7. Installed doxygen 1.8.13 again using `sudo apt-get install doxygen`
8. Ran doxygen on my code and config. Doxygen completes successfully as expected.

Why would doxygen 1.8.13 work fine, but 1.8.17 fail with the above output?

Comment: We have 2 problems here: 1) installation, would have been nice that this was reported through https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new. I have already analyzed the package and informed the the owner of doxygen of the problems there. 2) the clang problem. I'm not an expert on clang but it looks like the secon line (error: ..) gives a hint, maybe google for this...

Comment: @albert 1) I didn't know if this was an installation issue, or something I did wrong. 2) I did look up this in google and got nothing that would explain why Doxygen 1.8.13 would work, but 1.8.17 wouldn't.

Comment: I've added the clang tag so it might attract the attention of someone from the clang community to shine a light on the problem.